# Asynchronously processing large volume of messages in microservice

Tags: java, akka, microservices, batch-processing, akka-cluster

We are building a microservice in java. Responsibility of the microservice is to send emails by processing the incoming requests. To not impact the performance, we wanted to send the emails asynchronously. So we will queue the messages to a queue (in another microservice). We will have to support hundreds of tenants and have tens of queues per each tenant. So, the design should be scalable as the number of tenants and queues grow.

**Existing solution:**

We are going to deploy in k8s. So we have multiple instances of service running in docker containers on pods. Assuming we have 100 queues created (in other microservice - lets say queue service),

We have a background job that runs periodically every 10 seconds on every pod to detect new queues.
For every queue, we spin up 2 threads -
a) polling thread - that is responsible for polling messages from queue-service and put it in a local queue
b) Processing thread - responsible to process messages from the local queue. Processing of message means sending an email in our usecase

For each of the queues, we end up spinning polling and processing threads

This solution is obviously not scalable as we cannot keep on creating new threads for each queue on each of the pods

**My observation**:
I have come across a framework Akka, that seems to solve similar problems -
a) Sharing the workload across all available pods in cluster - Akka Cluster module
b) rebalancing the workload upon cluster topology changes

I am not familiar with Akka and actor based model and other concepts

Wanted to know if Akka is the right fit for the problem in hand? if yes, And how to model the design for my problem on a high level using Akka - Specially around how on each pod, I can allocate tenants and queues, and how to poll messages on each queue present in queue service and how to process the messages?

Comment: What solution did you end up using?

Answer (score 0):

The general approach I would take is to model each tenant as a cluster-sharded actor, which would spawn one actor for each queue associated with that tenant.  That spawned actor for the queue would manage the process of checking the queue, pulling messages off the queue, and acknowledging the message.

As for what that queue actor does with a pulled message, the general approach would be for it to hand off the actual work of sending an email to a different actor.  Depending on the requirements, everything from spawning an actor for the sole purpose of managing the send (good if there's not really any reusable infrastructure for sending an email) to maintaining a pool for the tenant (good if there's some expensive infrastructure that you can start once per actor and amortize over many sends) to handing off to a stream (which is implemented under the hood with actors, but you get a lot of potentially useful flow-control and control of resource consumption in the bargain) to send emails.

Comment: What is suggested in Akka to handle achieve the parallelism needed to process multiple messages while being able to ensure fair allocation of resources across queues. Should we take advantage of the fact that Akka actors themselves runs on individual threads and so spin off as many actors as the number of threads we wanted to achieve parallelism. Or is it still wise to have a design where all messages of all tenants are pushed to task queue and a centralized thread pool polling messages.

Comment: Within Akka, the actors get scheduled onto and off of threads (in the case of the standard dispatchers, a limited number of threads) based on whether they have a message in their mailbox (the dispatcher effectively is a task queue).

Comment: Is it wise to consider multiple actors per queue per tenant for improving parallelism, since only one message at a time is processed from an actor's mail box. This will also help to use the system resource efficiently when actors spawned for other queues has nothing to process. Is there a better alternative in Akka that does something similar ?

Comment: Also, for each queue in tenant, we would need to poll for messages from the queue on other service periodically. So, how to ensure that an actor can poll messages from external queue periodically. One option is to have a infinite loop where actor polls messages and sends to other actors, sleeps for certain time and then polls again. This approach is actually holding up a thread for queue actor that is spun off within jvm .Any other better way of doing this since threads allotted to actors is fixed?

Comment: I would tend to have a single actor per queue per tenant, unless it proves out that the throughput needed is more than a single actor per queue per tenant.  The amount of resources consumed by an actor with nothing to do is a few hundred bytes (plus whatever state that actor's behavior happens to hold), with no execution resources (e.g. threads, or CPU time more broadly) consumed.  There's a fairly rich API for scheduling messages to be sent (e.g. one could have each queue-consumer receive a `PollForMessages` message every 30 seconds (or as frequently as latency requirements/capacity allow)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Couple more questions. How a) Graceful and ungraceful shutdowns are handled in the following scenario ? Lets say as part of rolling upgrade, a node hosting one of the tenant actors need to be taken down, then is the actor automatically created onto other nodes and will the scheduling of messages works seamlessly ? What happens to the messages that queue consumer holds when shutdown happens on a node. b) Also, is there concept of replication in akka so that multiple instance of an entity id runs on different nodes for HA in scenarios of rolling upgrades or shutdowns

Comment: Also, what are the alternatives to Akka clustering ? Any technology provider that offers similar features to Akka clustering like cluster sharding etc with High Availability and Fault Tolerance ?

Comment: Migration of cluster sharded actors (and cluster singletons, as well) to other cluster nodes happens seamlessly.  During the move, the actor's mailbox is lost, so one does need to make the choice between at-most-once, at-least-once, and implementing something custom to provide exactly-once (because what "exactly-once" means in practice depends on the particulars of one's domain).  Replication of state is possible (I'm not aware of an off-the-shelf module beyond multi-datacenter persistence, which has a slightly-different usecase), though I tend to find that event- or command-sourcing...

Comment: ...to a replicated data store works better there.  As for alternatives, I'm not sure there's anything else on the JVM that does all these things.  Cluster sharding + persistence does effectively create an in-memory grid, so if that's all one's using Akka for, something like hazelcast is an alternative (but you're on your own for parallelism/concurrency).  For cluster-scale concurrency and parallelism, Spark and Flink are both good (but you're on your own for distributing changeable state).

Comment: hopfully one last question :-)  If we use scheduler/timer apis on an actor to ensure   messages are polled every x seconds/minutes, how does the scenario of nodeshutdowns handled ? From the docs , seems like entity actors within a shard may not get created on to new node until a message is sent to that entity actor. So, will there be a need for another actor - probably cluster singleton that takes care of monitoring all the entity actors in the system ? With this design of using schedulers for each entity actor, we seems to lost the benefit of automatic entity allocation during shutdown?